# Idiomatic way to tabulate observations after using split() in R

Tags: r

Is there a more idiomatic way to tabulate the number of observations is each data frame obtained from splitting a data frame on two columns in R? It's hard to describe so I wrote what I want to do.

```
splittable <- function(data,rowdata,coldata) {
        # data is the data frame for all your data
        # rowdata is a column from data
        # coldata is another column from data
        # This function returns a table counting the number of observations
        # from splitting the data by the rowdata and coldata values.
        splits <- as.data.frame(lapply(split(data,list(rowdata,coldata)),nrow))
        rowlevs <- levels(as.factor(rowdata))
        numrowlevs <- length(rowlevs)
        collevs <- levels(as.factor(coldata))
        outtable <- data.frame()
        for (i in seq(from=1,to=numrowlevs,by=1)) {
                indexes <- seq(from=i,to=length(splits),by=numrowlevs)
                tempdf <- as.data.frame(splits[indexes])
                names(tempdf) <- collevs
                outtable <- rbind(outtable,tempdf)
        }
        row.names(outtable) <- rowlevs
        return(outtable)
}
```

It seems like there should be a function that does this for me, but I can't find it.

Comment: Have you got an example of what your data look like, and then what you would like the data to look like?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share my data, but here's an example of what I'd like to see: ```splittable(mtcars,mtcars$gear,mtcars$carb)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just have reinvented the function `table`. Let's check with `mtcars`:

```r
splittable(mtcars, mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb)
#>   1 2 3 4 6 8
#> 3 3 4 3 5 0 0
#> 4 4 4 0 4 0 0
#> 5 0 2 0 1 1 1

table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb)
#>    
#>     1 2 3 4 6 8
#>   3 3 4 3 5 0 0
#>   4 4 4 0 4 0 0
#>   5 0 2 0 1 1 1
```